# GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo using Wildfly 8 causes NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to subscribe to GC notifications using GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo. The notifications work, but when I try use this mechanism inside Wildfly 8.2, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo
2017-02-06 08:40:09,156 ERROR [stderr] (Service Thread)     at com.vonage.metrics.GCNotificationListener.handleNotification(GCNotificationListener.java:28)
2017-02-06 08:40:09,156 ERROR [stderr] (Service Thread)     at  sun.management.NotificationEmitterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationEmitterSupport.java:156)
2017-02-06 08:40:09,157 ERROR [stderr] (Service Thread)     at sun.management.GarbageCollectorImpl.createGCNotification(GarbageCollectorImpl.java:147)
```

I found that in some cases you need to include dependencies in Jboss/Wildfly: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Do I need to somehow include the com.sun.* packages?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently encountered the same issue, only with WildFly `10.1.0.Final`.

The solution is to explicitly include `com.sun.management` classes using something like this in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system>
                <paths>
                    <path name="com/sun/management"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```